# How to write NSNumber in swift3?

Tags: swift

```
func updateCelsiusLabel() {
    if let value = celsiusValue {
        celsiusLabel.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(value)
    }
    else {
        celsiusLabel.text = "???"
    }
}


let numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let nf = NumberFormatter()
    nf.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
    nf.minimumFractionDigits = 0
    nf.maximumFractionDigits = 1
    return nf
    }()
```

I'm writing code that will creating a celsius format for my iphone application. I need it to handle converting a number into a decimal place.

I"m getting two error from my xcode compiler. Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'NSNumber'. the other problem, Type 'NumberFormatter.Style' has no member 'DecimalStyle' . need help working out the problem.

Comment: Is the "cannot convert" error on your 3rd line?

Comment: yes, it's on the 3rd line underline  red dotted line of value...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just for reference the application being built is ann exercise from the excellent book "IOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide" chapter 4.

**Problem 2 first:** "Type 'NumberFormatter.Style' has no member 'DecimalStyle'"
Swift 3 or Xcode 8 have depreciated NSNumberFormatter for NumberFormatter and it makes the code a little easier to read. Your code should work this way

```
let numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let nf = NumberFormatter()
    nf.numberStyle = .decimal
    nf.minimumFractionDigits = 0
    nf.maximumFractionDigits = 1
    return nf
}()
```

**Problem 1:** Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'NSNumber'
Joel Bell has the correct answer. Here is my approach

```
func updateCelsiuslabel() {
    if let value = celsiusValue {
        celsiusLabel.text = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: value))
    }
    else {
        celsiusLabel.text = "???"
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Problem 1 code is a lot cleaner. The other method work just as well by creating a constant type to NSNumber and using it.

Answer (score 1):

the function stringFromNumber is expecting you to pass it an NSNumber object but you are trying to pass it a Double. So you need to wrap your Double like so:

```
let myNumber = NSNumber(value: value)
celsiusLabel.text = numberFormatter.string(from: myNumber)
```

Also I believe it should just be

```
.decimal
```

Instead of

```
.decimalStyle
```

Note: This could be slightly different depending on the version of swift you are using.

Comment: I tried out your code, but it sorta worked. the compiler said to add this fix in and the error went away  'let myNumber = NSNumber(value: value)
            celsiusLabel.text = numberFormatter.string(from: myNumber)'

Comment: Yup that works. I believe that the compiler updated it to swift3 syntax I'll update my answer with the change

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This is Swift 2, which won't work for you because you're using Swift 3. I'm leaving the answer in case it's ever needed

Your first error is because NumberFormatter expects an NSNumber as an argument and you're passing it a double. Try

```
celsiusLabel.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber(double: value))
```

Your second error is because there's no decimalStyle in NumberFormatter.Style, but there is a decimal, so try

```
nf.numberStyle = .decimal
```

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/numberformatter.style) are all of the available style options

Comment: I change the numberformatter.style to the code you written and it worked, but first error I can't get it to work still..

Answer (score 0):

This is a Swift 2 to Swift 3 conversion error.  Many of the books written for early versions of Swoft are now obsolete - they cannot keep up with the annual changes in the Swift versions.  Swift is evolving faster than the authors can keep up.